# How to format a double with minimum precision

Tags: c#, format, double, precision, tostring

I have what I think is a simple problem.
I have a collection of doubles that I want to display in a listbox.
At a minimum, it should display three decimal places, however, if there are more than three digits, it should display them all.

I thought this would work, but it ends up just displaying the three decimal places:

```
    string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", freq.ToString("#0.000#", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), hz, band);
```

Perhaps I am missing something.  I don't really want to have to manually check the number of digits and transform the format block if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add more `"#"` into your format string:

```
freq.ToString("#0.000#############", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

`double` has [*15-16 digits* precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), so 13 `#` should make it work for all cases.

Comment: `freq = 1e-7/3` ?  Don't expect the size of the mantissa to tell you what the place value of the smallest significant digit is.

Comment: I was hoping that it wouldn't be as simple as that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
freq.ToString("0.000#")
```

That will give you at least 3 digits after the decimal separator.

So:

```
4.25   --> 4.250

4.2555 --> 4.2555
```